# Mobile Email using PSD slices

Tags: html, email, mobile, newsletter

I am looking for a way to resize our newsletter automatically to mobile. We usually have our emails in tabled layout using slices in Photoshop (around 100+ image slices). The thing is, there's too many variations of sizes for image width etc. for me to code it. Is there an easier way for this? I've read [this](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) and I kind of got the gist of the article, just that I can't find ones that discuss about tables in depth. Any advice would be helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine why you would need so many slices. Using Photoshop slices is definitely not best practice in email. In fact images should be limited to where necessary because in most cases, the reader will start with the images turned off by default in their email client. Many people read emails with the images off, and if they can't see it, it defeats the purpose.

I'd suggest you take a look at how you create your basic email newsletter and keep things very simple. Consistently rendering responsive emails are very hard to accomplish with so many different email clients. Trying to do it with more than a single column or two column type layout is simply asking for trouble.

Email on Acid has a solid [responsive template](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/emailology_a_free_responsive_email_template_using_media_queries_-_part_i) to get you started

There are also plenty of templates on [Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/templates/all/)

Comment: The thing is, the company wants the formatting to be exactly as it is done in our regular newsletter so i can't really do anything about the slices since it is, sadly, a must since they've been doing it for quite some time :/

Comment: Many phones just scale down the full fixed width for mobile anyway, so the easy fix is to avoid going responsive. Tell them their template is too jacked up and you'd have to redesign it to get it to work. You can have a email full of image (although not recommended), but it needs simplifying. There is no reason to have 100's of images in a page. If you can keep it as a simple grid it will make your job a lot easier

Comment: Alright. I'll try to suggest this tip the since I have no other answer. Thanks!